# Upload data and file with ng-file-upload

Tags: ng-file-upload

I am new to angular. I have searched a lot but didn't find a way to grab the data send through **Upload.upload()** of ng-file-upload. Though my file is uploaded into the destination folder using muter

Here is my controlled function which is called on upload click from the view.

```
$scope.doUpload = function() {
Upload.upload({
      url: '/api/upload/',
      data: {'sabhaDetails': sabhaDetails},
      file: sabhaFile,
      fileName: sabhaDetails.sabha_video_name
    });
}
```

In my route I have:

```
/ annotator page. (http://localhost:1337/api/upload)
annotationRouter.route('/upload')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    **console.log(req.data);**
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        res.json({ error_code:1, err_desc:err });
        return;
      }
      res.json({ error_code:0, err_desc:null });
    })
  });
```

But I am getting undefined for my req.data. Is there something wrong. How to grab the send data through upload?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node.js, all the form data apart from the files, should be allocated under the **body** key of your **request** object

In this case I think it should be req.body.data

The way I made it work sending everything on the **data** key:

```
Upload.upload({
      url: '/api/works/new',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {content: angular.toJson(controller.work), file: controller.thumb}
  }).
```

And then I can read as:

```
req.body.content
```

and the file as:

```
req.file.filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving `multipart/form-data` from ngf.

I don't know which server you are using, but I think you should check `req.form` rather than `req.data` or something.

Alternatively, you can use some external middleware, like [this](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)